# Unable to Install GDAL Using PIP on Python

Tags: python, pip, gdal

I'm trying to install gdal in python3.8.8 (Windows 10) and i'm getting below error
I have install Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 and reboot my  PC
Downgrade my Python from 3.9.5 to 3.8.8

```
C:\Program Files\Python38>pip install gdal
Collecting gdal
  Using cached GDAL-3.3.1.tar.gz (746 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: gdal
  Building wheel for gdal (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

command: 'c:\program files\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d1sufozs\\gdal\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d1sufozs\\gdal\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-q2jdc13d\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\program files\python38\Include\gdal'
         cwd: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d1sufozs\gdal\
    Complete output (136 lines):
    WARNING: numpy not available!  Array support will not be enabled
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo
    copying osgeo\gdal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo
    copying osgeo\gdalconst.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo
    copying osgeo\gdalnumeric.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo
    copying osgeo\gdal_array.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo
    copying osgeo\gnm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo
    copying osgeo\ogr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo
    copying osgeo\osr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo
    copying osgeo\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo
    copying osgeo\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal2tiles.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal2xyz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdalattachpct.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdalcompare.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdalmove.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_calc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_edit.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_fillnodata.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_merge.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_pansharpen.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_polygonize.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_proximity.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_retile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_sieve.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\ogrmerge.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\pct2rgb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\rgb2pct.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\array_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\batch_creator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\color_palette.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\color_table.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\extent_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\gdal_argparse.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\numpy_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\osr_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\progress.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\raster_creation.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\rectangle.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\assemblepoly.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\build_jp2_from_xml.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\classify.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\crs2crs2grid.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\densify.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\dump_jp2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\epsg_tr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\esri2wkt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\fft.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\fix_gpkg.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gcps2ogr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gcps2vec.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gcps2wld.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal2grd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalchksum.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalcopyproj.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalfilter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalident.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalimport.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalinfo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdallocationinfo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_auth.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_cp.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_create_pdf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_ls.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_lut.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_mkdir.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_remove_towgs84.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_rm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_rmdir.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_vrtmerge.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_zip.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\get_soundg.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\histrep.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\hsv_merge.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\jpeg_in_tiff_extract.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\load2odbc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\loslas2ntv2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\magphase.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\make_fuzzer_friendly_archive.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\mkgraticule.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogr2ogr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogr2vrt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogrinfo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogrupdate.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogr_build_junction_table.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogr_dispatch.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogr_layer_algebra.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\rel.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\tigerpoly.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\tile_extent_from_raster.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\tolatlong.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\validate_cloud_optimized_geotiff.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\validate_gpkg.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\validate_jp2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\val_repl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\vec_tr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\vec_tr_spat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\wcs_virtds_params.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\osgeo_utils\samples
    running build_ext
    building 'osgeo._gdal' extension
    building 'osgeo._gdalconst' extension
    building 'osgeo._osr' extension
    building 'osgeo._ogr' extension
    building 'osgeo._gnm' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\extensions
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I../../ogr/ogrsf_frmts -I../../gnm -I../../apps "-Ic:\program files\python38\include" "-Ic:\program files\python38\include" -I. "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpextensions/gdal_wrap.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\extensions/gdal_wrap.obj
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I../../ogr/ogrsf_frmts -I../../gnm -I../../apps "-Ic:\program files\python38\include" "-Ic:\program files\python38\include" -I. "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpextensions/gnm_wrap.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\extensions/gnm_wrap.obj
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I../../ogr/ogrsf_frmts -I../../gnm -I../../apps "-Ic:\program files\python38\include" "-Ic:\program files\python38\include" -I. "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcextensions/gdalconst_wrap.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\extensions/gdalconst_wrap.obj
    gnm_wrap.cpp
    gdal_wrap.cpp
    gdalconst_wrap.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I../../ogr/ogrsf_frmts -I../../gnm -I../../apps "-Ic:\program files\python38\include" "-Ic:\program files\python38\include" -I. "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpextensions/ogr_wrap.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\extensions/ogr_wrap.obj
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I../../ogr/ogrsf_frmts -I../../gnm -I../../apps "-Ic:\program files\python38\include" "-Ic:\program files\python38\include" -I. "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpextensions/osr_wrap.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\extensions/osr_wrap.obj
    ogr_wrap.cpp
    osr_wrap.cpp
    extensions/gdalconst_wrap.c(3018): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gdal.h': No such file or directory
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp(3191): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cpl_port.h': No such file or directory
    extensions/gnm_wrap.cpp(3135): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gdal.h': No such file or directory
    extensions/ogr_wrap.cpp(3153): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gdal.h': No such file or directory
    extensions/osr_wrap.cpp(3198): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cpl_string.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program files\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d1sufozs\\gdal\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d1sufozs\\gdal\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-q2jdc13d\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\program files\python38\Include\gdal' Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 21.2.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\program files\python38\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

C:\Program Files\Python38>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had recently installed GDAL in my windows system in order to install the geopandas package. For that, I went to this [website](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal) and downloaded the GDAL file with following filename as I am using Python 3.8.8 with Windows 64-bit system:

> GDAL‑3.3.1‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl

I pasted this *.whl file in the same folder as the terminal.
e.g.

> C:\Users\XYZ\Documents

Then I went to the Python terminal with the same path as above and typed the following:

```
pip install GDAL‑3.3.1‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl
```

And it worked for me.

Comment: i followed the instruction and manage to install gdal. both gdal and osgeo directory are created in C:\Program Files\Python38\Lib\site-packages.

I aslo added C:\Program Files\Python38\Lib to path under enviroment variables. I'm still unable to import gdal getting the following results


>>> import gdal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import gdal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdal'
>>>

Comment: You can check if your package is installed or not using pip list

Comment: You must use `from osgeo import gdal` nowadays.