# Trying to install GDAL - Python 3.9.9 - Pip - Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, gdal

I'm trying to install gdal library with `pip install gdal`

I'm using:

- python 3.9.9
- Windows 10

But i'm having this error :

> C:\Users\Thomas>pip install gdal
> Collecting gdal
> Using cached
> GDAL-3.4.1.tar.gz (755 kB)   Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
> Building wheels for collected packages: gdal   Building wheel for gdal
> (setup.py) ... error   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command:
> 'C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe'
> -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a6f2h5t3\gdal_bda2b7753d014f62ac5710c803768ff3\setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a6f2h5t3\gdal_bda2b7753d014f62ac5710c803768ff3\setup.py'"'"';f
> = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import
> setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-hfvfe4bv'
> cwd: C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a6f2h5t3\gdal_bda2b7753d014f62ac5710c803768ff3
> Complete output (118 lines):   running bdist_wheel   running build
> running build_py   creating build   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo   copying osgeo\gdal.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo   copying osgeo\gdalconst.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo   copying osgeo\gdalnumeric.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo   copying osgeo\gdal_array.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo   copying osgeo\gnm.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo   copying osgeo\ogr.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo   copying osgeo\osr.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo   copying osgeo\utils.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo   copying osgeo_*init*_.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo   creating
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal2tiles.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal2xyz.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdalattachpct.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdalcompare.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdalmove.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_calc.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_edit.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_fillnodata.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_merge.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_pansharpen.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_polygonize.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_proximity.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_retile.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_sieve.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\ogrmerge.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\pct2rgb.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\rgb2pct.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils_*init*_.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils   creating
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\auxiliary   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\array_util.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\auxiliary   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\base.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\auxiliary   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\batch_creator.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\auxiliary   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\color_palette.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\auxiliary   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\color_table.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\auxiliary   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\extent_util.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\auxiliary   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\gdal_argparse.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\auxiliary   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\numpy_util.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\auxiliary   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\osr_util.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\auxiliary   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\progress.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\auxiliary   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\raster_creation.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\auxiliary   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\rectangle.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\auxiliary   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\util.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\auxiliary   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary_*init*_.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\auxiliary   creating
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\assemblepoly.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\build_jp2_from_xml.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\classify.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\crs2crs2grid.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\densify.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\dump_jp2.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\epsg_tr.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\esri2wkt.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\fft.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\fix_gpkg.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gcps2ogr.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gcps2vec.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gcps2wld.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal2grd.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalchksum.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalcopyproj.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalfilter.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalident.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalimport.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalinfo.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdallocationinfo.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_auth.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_cp.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_create_pdf.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_ls.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_lut.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_mkdir.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_remove_towgs84.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_rm.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_rmdir.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_vrtmerge.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_zip.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\get_soundg.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\histrep.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\hsv_merge.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\jpeg_in_tiff_extract.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\load2odbc.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\loslas2ntv2.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\magphase.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\make_fuzzer_friendly_archive.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\mkgraticule.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogr2ogr.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogr2vrt.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogrinfo.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogrupdate.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogr_build_junction_table.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogr_dispatch.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogr_layer_algebra.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\rel.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\tigerpoly.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\tile_extent_from_raster.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\tolatlong.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\validate_cloud_optimized_geotiff.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\validate_gpkg.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\validate_jp2.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\val_repl.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\vec_tr.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\vec_tr_spat.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\wcs_virtds_params.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   copying
> gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples_*init*_.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples   running build_ext
> building 'osgeo._gdal' extension   building 'osgeo._ogr' extension
> building 'osgeo.*osr' extension   building 'osgeo.*gdalconst'
> extension   building 'osgeo.*gdal_array' extension   building
> 'osgeo.*gnm' extension   error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater
> is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools":
> https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
>
> ----------------------------------------   ERROR: Failed building wheel for gdal   Running setup.py clean for gdal Failed to build gdal
> Installing collected packages: gdal
> Running setup.py install for gdal ... error
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: 'C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe'
> -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a6f2h5t3\gdal_bda2b7753d014f62ac5710c803768ff3\setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a6f2h5t3\gdal_bda2b7753d014f62ac5710c803768ff3\setup.py'"'"';f
> = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import
> setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> install --record
> 'C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-cpcsirol\install-record.txt'
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\gdal'
> cwd: C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a6f2h5t3\gdal_bda2b7753d014f62ac5710c803768ff3
>
> Complete output (118 lines):
> running install
> running build
> running build_py
> creating build
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo
> copying osgeo\gdal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo
> copying osgeo\gdalconst.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo
> copying osgeo\gdalnumeric.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo
> copying osgeo\gdal_array.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo
> copying osgeo\gnm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo
> copying osgeo\ogr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo
> copying osgeo\osr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo
> copying osgeo\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo
> copying osgeo_*init**.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal2tiles.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal2xyz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdalattachpct.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdalcompare.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdalmove.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_calc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_edit.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_fillnodata.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_merge.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_pansharpen.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_polygonize.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_proximity.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_retile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\gdal_sieve.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\ogrmerge.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\pct2rgb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\rgb2pct.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils_*init**.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\array_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\batch_creator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\color_palette.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\color_table.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\extent_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\gdal_argparse.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\numpy_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\osr_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\progress.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\raster_creation.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\rectangle.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\auxiliary_*init**.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\auxiliary
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\assemblepoly.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\build_jp2_from_xml.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\classify.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\crs2crs2grid.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\densify.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\dump_jp2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\epsg_tr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\esri2wkt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\fft.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\fix_gpkg.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gcps2ogr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gcps2vec.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gcps2wld.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal2grd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalchksum.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalcopyproj.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalfilter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalident.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalimport.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdalinfo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdallocationinfo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_auth.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_cp.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_create_pdf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_ls.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_lut.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_mkdir.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_remove_towgs84.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_rm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_rmdir.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_vrtmerge.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\gdal_zip.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\get_soundg.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\histrep.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\hsv_merge.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\jpeg_in_tiff_extract.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\load2odbc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\loslas2ntv2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\magphase.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\make_fuzzer_friendly_archive.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\mkgraticule.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogr2ogr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogr2vrt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogrinfo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogrupdate.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogr_build_junction_table.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogr_dispatch.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\ogr_layer_algebra.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\rel.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\tigerpoly.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\tile_extent_from_raster.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\tolatlong.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\validate_cloud_optimized_geotiff.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\validate_gpkg.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\validate_jp2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\val_repl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\vec_tr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\vec_tr_spat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples\wcs_virtds_params.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> copying gdal-utils\osgeo_utils\samples_*init**.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\osgeo_utils\samples
> running build_ext
> building 'osgeo._gdal' extension
> building 'osgeo._ogr' extension
> building 'osgeo._gnm' extension
> building 'osgeo._gdalconst' extension
> building 'osgeo._osr' extension
> building 'osgeo._gdal_array' extension
> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools":
> https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
> ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> 'C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe'
> -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a6f2h5t3\gdal_bda2b7753d014f62ac5710c803768ff3\setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a6f2h5t3\gdal_bda2b7753d014f62ac5710c803768ff3\setup.py'"'"';f
> = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import
> setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> install --record
> 'C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-cpcsirol\install-record.txt'
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\gdal'
> Check the logs for full command output.

I tried to install last version of microsoft visual C++ but it doesn't change anything..

[image]

Does somebody have an idea about what should I try ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68816555/unable-to-install-gdal-using-pip-on-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only GDAL I made work on Windows 10 was from the *Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages by Christoph Gohlke* [Here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal)

Just for curiosity the [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/index.html) project also [recommend that unofficial repository](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/install.html#installing-with-pip) for Windows.
If it dies try [this](http://eturnbull.ca/pythonlibs/) another unofficial source. This is kindly provided by Erin Turnbull from the original Christoph Gohlke site.

Comment: Thanks ! I will try this :)

Comment: And now it is saddly [discontinued](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/vcaibq/christoph_gohlkes_windows_wheels_site_is_shutting/)...

Comment: @tgrandje thanks but we have an alternative mirror http://eturnbull.ca/pythonlibs/ thanks to Erin Turnbull.

Comment: @iambr Yes I've seen it, but he hasn't said he'd keep up with future releases though. As he said in reddit : "But Im not sure I can keep up with compiling new binaries for new releases." I sincerely hope he will, but suspect it's gonna be too big a task. (I think I saw something more definitive about that earlier, but I can't find it again).

Comment: @tgrandje sure. Crossing my fingers... tks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @iambr, it works perfectly !

After downloading the right Extension Packages by Christoph Gohlke [Here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal)

I installed the package with pip

```
py -3.9 -m pip install D:\Downloads\GDAL-3.4.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
```

or (depending the python version)

```
py -3.10 -m pip install D:\Downloads\GDAL-3.4.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: Sorry the link is invalid now. Would you give some advice? Thank you very much!

Comment: can you try again ? it still look valid for me